# Java split list

Tags: java

I have a assignment to create a linked list and split into two sublist
and right now I have a error with my code. If any one can help me with my code, I can't figure  out where needs to be change every since i change some it gave me more error.

```
public class UnorderedLinkedList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends LinkedList<T>
{
    public void splitMid(LinkedList<String> subList)
    {
        LinkedList<T> current;//the head pointer
        LinkedList<T> mid;//the mid point 

        //Node first = firstNode;
        //Node last = firstNode;

        //Node subListFirst;
        //Node subListLast;
        int i;

        if(head == null)
        {
            subList.head = null;
            subList.last = null;
            subList.count = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            //mid =
            head = null;
            current = head.next;
            i = 1;

            if(current != null)
                current = current.next;

            while(current != null)
            {
                mid = mid.next;
                current = current.next;
                i++;

                if(current != null)
                    current = current.next;
            }

             subList.head = head.next;
             subList.last = last;
             last = mid ;
             last.next = null;

             subList.count = count - i;
             count = i;
        }
    }
}
```

## Error message

> G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedList.java:184: error: cannot find symbol subList.count = 0;
>
> symbol:   variable count.
>
> location: variable subList of type LinkedList.Node
>
> where T,E are type-variables:
>
> T extends Object declared in class LinkedList.
>
> E extends Comparable declared in class LinkedList.UnorderedLinkedList

## My main class:

```
public void main(String args[])
{
    LinkedList<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    LinkedList<Integer> subList = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    myList.addLast(34);
    myList.addLast(65);
    myList.addLast(87);
    myList.addLast(29);
    myList.addLast(12);

    myList.splitMid( subList);
}
```

## error message

> G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedTest.java:31: error: cannot find symbol.
>
> myList.splitMid(subList);
>
> symbol:   method splitMid(LinkedList)
>
> location: variable myList of type LinkedList

Comment: whats ur meaing about "split into two sublist"???

Answer (score 1):

About compilation error:

You are using instance of `LinkedList` to call the method that you have defined for class `UnorderedLinkedList`

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedList.java:184: error: cannot find symbol subList.count = 0;
```

try to delete subList.count; its not necessary to assign value for count;

2.

```
G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedTest.java:31: error: cannot find symbol.

myList.splitMid(subList);
```

do this:

```
UnorderedLinkedList<Integer> myList = new UnorderedLinkedList<Integer>();
```

Comment: Note that `myList` will need to be typed as `UnorderedLinkedList` in order to call `splitMid` on it.

Comment: `myList.splitMid(subList);` won't compile because `myList` is statically typed as `LinkedList`, which doesn't declare `splitMid`. `myList` must be declared as `UnorderedLinkedList`.

Comment: Okay cool... `subList.size() = 0` won't compile either, sorry.

Comment: try to delete subList.count; its not necessary to assign value for count;

Comment: try to delete subList.count; its not necessary to assign value for count;

Comment: So i just delete the subList.count just that? how about the subList.head, subList.last. And i made change to my main class, change tp UnorderedLinkedList<Integer>myList = new UnorderedLinkedList<Integer>(); but gave a error again:

Comment: G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        UnorderedLinkedList<Integer> myList = new UnorderedLinkedList<Integer>();
  symbol:   class UnorderedLinkedList
  location: class LinkedTest<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class LinkedTest
G:\LinkedList\src\LinkedTest.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        UnorderedLinkedList<Integer> subList = new UnorderedLinkedList<Integer>();
  symbol:   class UnorderedLinkedList
  location: class LinkedTest<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class LinkedTest